# T-SQL Test for checking duplicates in a column and returning if it passes or fails check

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, duplicates, unique

I am running a data quality check on multiple tables and columns in a database.

If the column contains at least one duplciate, it fails the test and PassFail returns 0. Likewise if it contains no duplicates, it passses the test and PassFail returns 1.

The 1s and 0s from PassFail is then fed to an average to calculate an overall data quality score.

```
SELECT  
    '[Plant.Asset]'     AS TableName
    ,'[ASSETNUM]'       AS ColumnName
    ,COUNT(1)           AS TotalRows
    ,0                  AS PassFail
FROM Plant.Asset a
INNER JOIN Plant.Loc AS B ON A.LOCATION = B.LOCATION
GROUP BY 
    A.ASSETNUM 
HAVING
    COUNT(A.ASSETNUM) > 1
```

The script returns correctly when there are duplicates, **however when there are no duplicates, the table returns nothing.**

If there are duplciates the output is

```
TableName     ColumnName    TotalRows   PassFail
Plant.Asset   ASSETNUM      1234            0
```

If there are no duplicates, the output is currently blank

```
TableName     ColumnName    TotalRows   PassFail
```

If there are no duplicates, the output should be

```
TableName     ColumnName    TotalRows   PassFail
Plant.Asset   ASSETNUM      0               1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want *case* expression :

```
SELECT 'Plant.Asset' AS [TableName], A.ASSETNUM AS [ColumnName], COUNT(1) AS TotalRows,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS PassFail
FROM Plant.Asset a INNER JOIN 
     Plant.Loc AS B 
     ON A.LOCATION = B.LOCATION
GROUP BY A.ASSETNUM;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yogesh. Unfortunetly that results in 6500 rows in the table. For when there are no duplicates, I just want one row with TotalRows = 0 and PassFail = 1

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this with `Stored Procedure` so I assume this SELECT is part of a stored procedure.   A quick and easy way to handle this would be to INSERT the results of your query into a table variable or temp table:

```
INSERT INTO @ResultTable (TableName, ColumnName, TotalRows, PassFail)
SELECT  
    '[Plant.Asset]'     AS TableName
    ,'[ASSETNUM]'       AS ColumnName
    ,COUNT(1)           AS TotalRows
    ,0                  AS PassFail
FROM Plant.Asset a
INNER JOIN Plant.Loc AS B ON A.LOCATION = B.LOCATION
GROUP BY 
    A.ASSETNUM 
HAVING
    COUNT(A.ASSETNUM) > 1;
```

Then check that table and either return it or your default result, since you have a static result that you want to return if there are no duplicates:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ResultTable > 0)
  SELECT * FROM @ResultTable;
ELSE
  SELECT 
        '[Plant.Asset]'     AS TableName
        ,'[ASSETNUM]'       AS ColumnName
        ,0                  AS TotalRows
        ,1                  AS PassFail
```